# MS access Database Connection using ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I am using ASP for the first time.  I have connected to a database access using ASP but I cannot fetch the data from my MS Access Database. I don't even know whether I'm connected to my Database. I guess I'm doing it wrong.

I'm using the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<%
    set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    conn.Open "C:\Amit Chadwick\IPTC\Database\IPTC.mdb"

    set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    rs.Open "Select * from Image_Data", conn%>
    <table border="1" width="100%">
    <%do until rs.EOF%>
    <tr>    
    <%for each x in rs.Fields%>
    <td><%Response.Write(x.value)%></td>
    <%next
    rs.MoveNext%>
    </tr>
    <%loop
    rs.close
    conn.close
%>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is very vague. Could you fix your post by removing all the "enter code here" subs? And replacing them by relevant code?

Comment: @user1972710, Can you add correct code?

Comment: @Robuust Sorry about that, I have removed it now.

Comment: Are you getting any Error Messages?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, i found your code helpful for me ,i successfully connected to MS Access by using your code.i also did some modifications which may be helpful for you.

```
<%
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open "C:\vb\mydb.mdb"
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open "Select * from student", conn
do until rs.EOF
Response.Write(rs.Fields("roll"))
Response.Write(rs.Fields("name"))
Response.Write(rs.Fields("age"))
rs.MoveNext
loop
rs.close
conn.close
%>
```